# Java spring boot related session timeout

Tags: web-applications

I need to create session timeout and after the particular minute it needs to redirect to the login page. I am using spring boot and I am not having Web.xml files... Kindly share your ideas.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to StackOverflow! Can you tell us what you tried so far?

Comment: I have added server.servlet.session-timeout=120, in application properties file.. It is not working..